# Can't call class which was defined with exec earlier

Tags: python, class

I'm running this code:

```
class timetable(object):
    def __init__(self, date):
        self.date = date
    def outGet(self):
        print("timetable output: ", self.date)

class timetableUpperClass(object):
    def newSubject(self, subjectDate):
        # Define new Class
        execThis = ("day_" + str(subjectDate) + " = timetable(" + str(subjectDate) + ")")
        exec(execThis)

        # Get output
        execThisTwo = ("day_" + str(subjectDate) + ".outGet()")
        print("working command: ", execThisTwo)
        exec(execThisTwo)

p = timetableUpperClass()
p.newSubject(20170829)
```

This code runs as expected. Output:

```
working command: day_20170829.outGet()
timetable output:  20170829
```

But when I try to add this line to the end of the python-document:

```
day_20170829.outGet()
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "huh.py", line 23, in <module>
    day_20170829.outGet()
NameError: name 'day_20170829' is not defined
```

I don't get why exec() runs properly and the other doesn't.

I'm running Python 3.5.2 on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This is bad practice. There's really no excuse for using `exec` here.

Comment: you want a `dict`ionary of integers.

Comment: Why are you going to the trouble of dynamically generating names for single-use local variables whose names don't matter? Even if the name somehow mattered, you should be using a `dict` instead: `day[subjectDate] = timetable(subjectDate)`.

Comment: Modifying local variables with `exec` is unsupported in Python 3, and then you try to find the object in the *globals*?

Comment: Also, no, `exec(execThis)` is not defining a new class.

Comment: @user2357112 Why not? Its running 'day_20170829 = timetable(20170829)'

Comment: @vexE: Which doesn't define a new class.

Comment: Ok. Maybe I'm misunderstanding how exec() works. :D

Comment: Do not use `exec` to do this, it is totally unnecessary and simply bad design all around.

Comment: @vexE No, you are misunderstanding what defining a class means. `timetable(20170829)` does not define a new class.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Is this called instantiation?

Comment: Yes, this instantiates an *instance of the class `timetable`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

One way to work with your data is to use a dictionary and it might be best to keep everything here in one class.

Taking your code and modifying it to get what I think it is you are trying to accomplish done I have this code:

```
class timetableUpperClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.store_data = {}

    def outGet(self, date):
        return "timetable output: {}".format(date)
        print("timetable output: {}".format(date))

    def newSubject(self, subjectDate):
        self.store_data["day_{}".format(subjectDate)] = self.outGet(str(subjectDate))
        print("working command: ", self.store_data["day_{}".format(subjectDate)])

p = timetableUpperClass()
p.newSubject(20170829)
p.outGet(p.store_data["day_20170829"])
```

Let me know what you think about this code or if you have questions on the use of the `self.store_data` dict.

As most have pointed out you don't need and probably should not use exec.

However for accuracy and to provide the solution to fix your issue with `day_20170829.outGet()` you can add variables to the global name space with `exec` using `globals()` as a 2nd argument to `exec`.

So for lines:

```
exec(execThis)
```

and

```
exec(execThisTwo)
```

change them to:

```
exec(execThis, globals())
```

and

```
exec(execThisTwo, globals())
```

This should allow `day_20170829.outGet()` to print the results you were trying to get.

Take this example, If we create a function and use exec to create a variable in the global name space we can then print that variables string outside of the function:

```
def create_vars_in_global():
        exec("my_var = 'this is in the global'", globals())

create_vars_in_global()

print(my_var)
```

Results:

```
this is in the global
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Here is the edited version of your code:

```
class timetable(object):
    def __init__(self, date):
        self.date = date
    def outGet(self):
        print("timetable output: ", self.date)

class timetableUpperClass(object):
    def newSubject(self, subjectDate):
        # Define new Class
        execThis = ("day_" + str(subjectDate) + " = timetable(" + str(subjectDate) + ")")
        exec(execThis, globals())

        # Get output
        execThisTwo = ("day_" + str(subjectDate) + ".outGet()")
        print("working command: ", execThisTwo)
        exec(execThisTwo, globals())

p = timetableUpperClass()
p.newSubject(20170829)
```

Comment: Your example works, but I can't figure out how I can get my code running. Anyways. Thank you! I will try to get it working with the aid of a dictionary.

Comment: @vexE I have added an edited version of your code that should work fine. However I do agree that working with a dictionary would be best for this issue as well.

Comment: @vexE I have added an example using a dictionary that I think would be close to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: That's not what I want to achieve. I want to create for each day I give my program, to create a new instance of timetable which holds some information. I will work around this now by using JSON. This works a lot easier.

Comment: @vexE that should be really easy to automate. You can have an if statement that will compares today's date with the date of already saved timetables and if they do not match then create new timetable. I have done something similar in my calendar program but for an entire month of the year. So my program once it opens will make sure the date exist first and if not it creates it.

Comment: You can do it even easier: `jsonTimetable["myClass"]["20170829"] = yourJsonHere`

Comment: @vexE Mine uses the json file as the dict. So all data is save to the json and then the json is loaded as a dict and I manipulate date from there.

Answer (score 1):

## How exec() works:

When you call exec() it separates any variables from the main script. This means that if you are defining a variable in exec then you will have to print it etc in exec()

For example:

```
exec("a = 10")    #Defining a
print(a)          #This would give an error
exec("print(a)")  #This would print a
```

It is best practice to NOT use exec(), it comes with big security issues and it is just in general better to try and find a workaround if possible

## Workaround using dictionaries:

Instead of using exec(), use a dictionary

I'm assuming you know how this works, but here is an example:

```
a = {1:"a", 2:"b", 3:"c"}
print(a[1])
print(a[2])
print(a[3])
```

Would output:

```
'a'
'b'
'c'
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that exec() separates any variable.

Comment: @vexE I have added a section explaining a workaround for this problem as well. I assume you know how dictionaries work ;)

Comment: Yes. Thank you! Dictionaries work kinda like JSON, right?

Comment: Creating or modifying variables with `exec` using the default locals is officially unsupported. It may sometimes look like such assignments happen in a separate namespace, or it may sometimes look like such assignments are [completely forgotten](https://ideone.com/dPd0Mu) after the `exec` call finishes, or it may sometimes look like such assignments behave just like regular assignments. Even accessing the variables from subsequent `exec` calls isn't guaranteed to be safe.

Comment: @vexE Dictonaries are basically the same as real life dictionaries! Haha! In my example I used `a = {1:"a", 2:"b", 3:"c"}`. The `3:'c'` would mean that the number `3` means `'c'`, so whenever I look in the dictionary called `a` and look at what `3` means, it will say `3 = 'c'` and output `'c'`

Comment: @vexE techincally, no. JSON is a text-based [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) format that supports data structures like "json objects" which will get deserialized into Python `dict` objects, and  "json arrays" which get deserialized into Python `list` objects. So, no, JSON doesn't work like a dictionary, that would be a category error, but if youv'e worked with JSON data, you've almost certainly worked with a `dict`, even if you didn't know it at the time.

Comment: @vexE If this answered your question, make sure to accept it as the answer and upvote! :D

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's what I meant: You basically handle dicts like JSON.

Comment: @vexE Again, not *precisely* speaking.  JSON data can be *deserialized into a `dict`*, which you then work with. You shouldn't working with JSON data directly, which is **text**, unless you are doing something super-hacky.  It may seem like a pedantic point, but I think it is important to distinguish between the storage format and the in-memory data-structure. One could store a data-structure in a database as a `pickle`, but you wouldn't say that you work with a `dict` like you work with a data-base... at least, that *isn't really what you mean*. In programming, you should try to be precise.

Comment: @Ruler Of The World I'll try getting the code running with a dict tomorrow. I'm a bit tired now :d. If it will work with a dict, I'll will accept your answer.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I get what you're saying. Thank's for pointing that out!

Comment: That's what I want to achieve: I want to create multiple instances of 'timetable' for each day I will add. Each instance will hold e.g. subject and teacher. I think I'm better off with using JSON at this point.

Comment: @vexE So you want to duplicate the dict?

Comment: @vexE If you want to make the dict hold the teacher and lesson, use this: `timetable = {"day1":["lesson1", "teacher1"], "day2":["lesson2", "teacher2"]}`

Comment: @Ruler Of The World Thank you! But I think JSON is easier to handle with other languages. I have no idea atm where this peace of software will take me :D I'm also more experienced with JSON.

Comment: @vexE Do whatever your more comfortable with :) I do agree with you it took me a while to learn how python dicts worked, haha ;)

Answer (score 0):

`exec` is executed in the current namespace, creating a local variable, but you cannot access this local variable directly. Better use dictionaries:

```
day = {}
day[subjectDate] = timetable(subjectDate)
day[subjectDate].outGet()
```